# Change content button on click form

Tags: php, forms, button, confirm

I have a contact form for people to fill in if they want to contact me. A php page does the action of sending the stuff to my emailadress.

2 problems:

1. I want the content of the confirm button to change to: "MESSAGE SEND!" when someone clicks on the button. But I want it to change back to original state after 3 sec.
2. When you click the button it loads the php page in my browser! That's not what I want. I just want the button to send me an email and not to go to another page.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you are going to have to use Javascript and AJAX. And why don't you use a javascript library like Jquery?

Assuming you are going to use it, the code goes like this.

HTML:

```
<form id="yourForm">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourForm').submit(function(event){
        $('.submitBtn').attr('value','MESSAGE SEND');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.submitBtn').attr('value','OK');
        }, 3000);

        var stuff = $('#yourForm').serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'your_php_code.php', 
            data:{
                'stuff':stuff,                
            }
            ,success: function( response ){
                alert('OK');
            }
        });

        //Prevents form submission
        return false;        
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    parse_str($_POST['stuff']);
    mail("youremail@gmail.com", "subject", $name);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

1.

```
<input type="button" onclick="showLoad()" id="send" name="send" value="SEND"/>
<script>
function showLoad() {
document.getElementById('send').value="MESSAGE SEND!";
setTimeout(swap, 3000);
}
function swap() {
document.getElementById('send').value="SEND";
}
</script>
```

2.

```
<form action="" method="post">
......
......
/*your html code*/
<input type="button" onclick="showLoad()" id="send" name="send" value="SEND"/>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_post['send']))
{
/*your mail function*/
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'm trying to implement point 1, but it's not working... The type of input i'm using is type="submit". Does this make a difference? I'm going to try point 2 when point 1 works. Could you help me out?

Comment: Sorry it was my problem. Now u can check as i have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

For your 1 Problem, you'll Need JavaScript to Change the Button behavior, for your 2 Problem just make a Header Redirect from the PHP Script doing the Action

Comment: Could you show how this works? (you solution to Problem 2)?

Comment: Just add: header('Location: yourstartingpage.php'); straight before ?>